# How does one determine if a Data base connection is open or close using the R Oracle package in R?

Tags: r, oracle, roracle

I am using the ROracle package in R to connect to an oracle database.
Using the below code block I establish a connection to the oracle DB.

```
drv <- dbDriver("Oracle")
con <- dbConnect(drv, user=UName, password=Pword, dbname = Dbname )
```

I can close the connection using the below command

```
dbDisconnect(con)
```

In order to ensure that connections are closed properly when error occurs I want to know the status of the connection. As in if it has been closed or if it is still open.

Comment: Check ?DBI::dbListConnections

Comment: Or maybe `DBI::dbIsValid`.

Comment: @RajaSaha: That seems to be helpful. I am trying to use `if(length(dbListConnections(drv)) > 0)` to check the connection status.

Comment: @Scarabee: Unfortunately my `con` object is of class `OraConnection`. Hence it does not work with `DBI::dbIsValid`. I got the following error. _Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘dbIsValid’ for signature ‘"OraConnection"’_ . Any suggestions to circumvent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do the following :

```
drv <- ROracle::Oracle()
sapply(ROracle::dbListConnections(drv), ROracle::dbDisconnect)
```